# Controlar Inicio de Session con campo de estado Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, login

Espero podais ayudarme.

Estoy usando el login que ofrece laravel por defecto para el control de inicio de session, pero tengo un problema. Yo añadí un campo a la tabla Users, llamado Estado, porque no quiero eliminar de forma permanente a mi usuario, solo desactivarlo, para poder conservarlo en la base de datos y reactivarlo cuando yo lo requiera.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Donde puedo controlar que si el estado sea 'inactivo' no me deje ingresar? Estoy usando Laravel 5.6

Comment: Recuerda que para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida siempre es recomendable venga acompañada de lo que has intentado o investigado al momento, de otro modo puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Podrías utilizar softdeletes, o bien, cambiar la función de login por default como lo menciona la documentación en https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que modificar el LoginController de tu proyecto y agregarle la condición de estado asi como te muestro. el campo activo la debes cambiar por tu campo estado

```
if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $form->input('email'), 'password' => $form->input('password'),'activo'=> 1],$form->input('remember'))) 
{
    .....
}
```